# Electron frame: false not working

Tags: javascript, electron

for some reason in my electron app, whenever I set `frame: false` in `BrowserWindow` options, the frame still persists in windows 10 (build 1709), and does not disable. Here is my `BrowserWindow`:

```
const win = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
        width: 1440,
        height: 960,
        frame: false,
        titleBarStyle: 'hidden',
        nodeIntegrationInWorker: true,
        nodeIntegration: false
        // devTools: false
    }
});
```

I've tried removing everything except `frame: false` even, to no avail. My friend also claims his window frame is also not being removed on his Mac as well. I'm currently using electron version 1.8.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read carefully the doc about [new BrowserWindow()](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#new-browserwindowoptions):

While `nodeIntegrationInWorker`, `nodeIntegration`, `devTools` are indeed properties of `webPreferences`, all the other ones belong to the top-level `options` object.

Please try this instead:

```
const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1440,
    height: 960,
    frame: false,
    titleBarStyle: 'hidden',
    webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegrationInWorker: true,
        nodeIntegration: false
        // devTools: false
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I must have skipped over this while searching for some completely different cause to the issue. Just needed a second pair of eyes on that was all. I will mark as an answer first thing when I’m able to confirm this, but I’m 100% sure that’s the cause.

Answer (score 2):

Easy -

```
width: 1440,
height: 960,
frame: false,
titleBarStyle: 'hidden',
```

Are **not** webPreferences. Move them all out of the webPrefrences object and it will work properly.

```
const win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1440,
        height: 960,
        frame: false,
        titleBarStyle: 'hidden',
        webPreferences: {
           nodeIntegrationInWorker: true,
           nodeIntegration: false
        }
});
```

Comment: `nodeIntegration` and `nodeIntegrationInWorker` should be under `webPreferences` though. You might want to edit the answer.